# Show Title Tag on Hover - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, tags, mouseover, jquery-hover

I currently have my title tags HIDDEN using the following jquery:

```
/** To hide title tag that shows on hover **/
jQuery('document').ready(function($){
    $('[title]').removeAttr('title');
});
```

1. How can I **re-show title tag for a specific image**?  Specifically, I have some icons in my top-left navigation bar I want title tags to show for on hover.  I believe this is the CSS ID: ".top-bar ul>li a"
2. Is my method for hiding title tags a good way to do it without being hurt in my google search results?

Website is **[greenenvysupply.com](http://greenenvysupply.com)**
Thank you!!

***EDIT***
Maybe this would be easier: The only thing I want to have title tags hidden from is my main navigation menu (product categories).  Instead of having jquery set to hide all tags, how can I hide just the category menu and dropdown submenus? HIDE, NOT REMOVE, IF POSSIBLE.

Comment: You have _removed_ them.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Will using _hideAttr_ instead of _removeAttr_ work?

Comment: Sorry frnd,I just send you the wrong code.so i want to delete .But Dont worry frnd..I will come back soon..Stay tune

Answer (score 1):

I you want to show the title of an image during hover use that corresponding "id".For example.

```
<img src="smiley.gif" title="123" id="sml_img" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
```

Use this script where you want to show the title again

```
 $("#sml_img").attr("title","--enter the title--");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use our on method.Its only pure java script and dont want to include or attach any files. Here is an example to hide on mouse over and displays at mouseOut event.We can create more effect by adding more styles like transition,opacity,alpha etc...If this is so useful to you,then i'll add more styles.

But justnow You can modify this source with your on id and check this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function showImage(id) {
        var img = document.getElementById(id);
        img.style.visibility = 'visible';        
    }

    function setImageVisible(id) {
        var img = document.getElementById(id);
        img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }   
</script>

<style type="text/css">

.hid_lnk{
    background-color:#999999;
    height:100px;
    margin:10px;
    width:150px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    }   
a img{

    height:100px;
}

</style>
```

Here isthe html section..

```
<div class="hid_lnk" onmouseout="javascript:showImage('i1')" onmouseover="javascript:setImageVisible('i1', false)" >
        <a href="#"><img id="i1"   src="http://www.shop.justpcs.co.za/image/cache/data/logos/hp-logo-500x500.png" ></img></a>
      </div>
```

Hope this will help ..

regds..

Comment: Thank you for the response Vijay.  Is there such thing as a hide attribute for jquery i.e. something like .hideAttr("title")? I'm worried about search ranking being hurt